# C# LINQ Question

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
var query = from lookup in dataset.Tables["MBDDX_LOOKUP"].AsEnumerable()
                    where
                        lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value") == "Oncology"

                    select new
                    {
                        lookupID = lookup.Field<long>("ID")
                    };
```

This returns exactly what I want.  However, I also want to check another field within the where clause and 'select new' that also.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

EDIT:  The second piece of data that I wish to extract is also within the MBDDX_LOOKUP field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to check the same field for two possible values, use the OR operator `||`:

```
var query = from lookup in dataset.Tables["MBDDX_LOOKUP"].AsEnumerable()
        where lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value") == "Oncology" ||
              lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value") == "Zoology"
        select new {
            lookupID = lookup.Field<long>("ID"),
            lookup = lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value")
        };
```

Comment: Excellent thanks.  I feel a little stupid now, as I should have realised that.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add another condition using the and operator `&&`.

```
var query = from lookup in dataset.Tables["MBDDX_LOOKUP"].AsEnumerable()
            where lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value") == "Oncology" &&
                  lookup.Field<string>("anotherlookup_value") == "Zoology"
            select new {
                lookupID = lookup.Field<long>("ID"),
                lookup = lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value")
            };
```

Comment: Hi,  The second piece of data that I need is also in the lookup_value field.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from lookup in dataset.Tables["MBDDX_LOOKUP"].AsEnumerable()
                where
                    lookup.Field<string>("lookup_value") == "Oncology" &&
                    lookup.Field<string>("another_field") == "foo"

                select new
                {
                    lookupID = lookup.Field<long>("ID"),
                    another_field = lookup.Field<string>("another_field")
                };
```